# Reset Password Strategy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider

I have a custom Register form which includes a security question and answer - works fine.

However, I have the following reset password logic which only works if the `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` property is set to false in my Web.Config file. Can someone show me a recommended way to code the question and answer logic into my ResetPassword code-behind? Is another trip to the DB necessary here?

```
public void ResetPassword_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string newPassword;
    u = Membership.GetUser(UsernameTextBox.Text, false);
    newPassword = u.ResetPassword();

    if (newPassword != null)
    {
        Msg.Text 
            = "Password reset. Your new password is: " 
                + Server.HtmlEncode(newPassword);
    }
    else
    {
        Msg.Text 
            = "Password reset failed. Please re-enter your values.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you look over this free resource: http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[MembershipUser.PasswordQuestion Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.passwordquestion.aspx)

"If RequiresQuestionAndAnswer is true, then the password answer for a membership user must be supplied to the GetPassword and ResetPassword methods."